# Laravel query builder - how to select a model whereHas one of multiple relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, wherehas

I have a `Shop` model that can has three relationships: `Specials`, `Discounts` and `ThrowOuts`. I want to select all `Shop`s that have data in any one of those three relationships, but mask the ones that don't have any at all.

I also want to limit the search results based on properties of the `Shop` itself:

```
Shop::where('state', $state)
    ->whereHas('Specials')
    ->whereHas('Discounts ')
    ->whereHas('ThrowOuts')
```

This query requires that all the relationships have data - none can be blank

```
Shop::where('state', $state)
    ->orWhereHas('Specials')
    ->orWhereHas('Discounts ')
    ->orWhereHas('ThrowOuts')
```

Using `orWhereHas` returns all of the shops that have any data in those relationships *regardless of the first "where"* so I get shops from all over the country as well.

Answer (score 0):

...aaand I've just answered my own question - group the results of the first where, and run the relationship queries on that grouping instead:

```
Shop::where('state', $state)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->orWhereHas('Specials')
                     ->orWhereHas('Discounts ')
                     ->orWhereHas('ThrowOuts');
    });
```